# Problem defining entry/exit in a pinescript v5 strategy

Tags: pine-script

I was making a simple RSI divergence strategy to test longs on bullish divergence but my code is taking NO trades. I don't know why, please help.

The initial code block is from a perfectly fine RSI divergence indicator from Libertus.

The strategy code starts below `//strategy code`

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © rypto_dynasty

//@version=5
strategy("RSI div strategy", overlay=true)

len = input.int(14, minval=1, title='RSI Length')
ob = input.int(defval=70, title='Overbought', minval=0, maxval=100)
os = input.int(defval=30, title='Oversold', minval=0, maxval=100)
i_stop_prcnt = input.float(title='Stop percentage?', defval=0.5)
i_exposure = input.float(title='Exposure?', defval=0.5)
i_period_start = input.time(timestamp("1 Apr 2022 00:00 +0300"), "Period start")
i_period_end = input.time(timestamp("14 Apr 2022 00:00 +0300"), 'Period end')
// RSI code
rsi = ta.rsi(close, len)
band1 = hline(ob)
band0 = hline(os)
plot(rsi, color=rsi > ob or rsi < os ? color.new(color.red, 0) : color.new(color.black, 0))
fill(band1, band0, color=color.new(color.purple, 97))

// DIVS code
piv = input(false, 'Hide pivots?')
shrt = input(false, 'Shorter labels?')
hidel = input(false, 'Hide labels and color background')
xbars = input.int(defval=90, title='Div lookback period (bars)?', minval=1)
hb = math.abs(ta.highestbars(rsi, xbars))  // Finds bar with highest value in last X bars
lb = math.abs(ta.lowestbars(rsi, xbars))  // Finds bar with lowest value in last X bars

// Defining variable values, mandatory in Pine 3
max = float(na)
max_rsi = float(na)
min = float(na)
min_rsi = float(na)
pivoth = bool(na)
pivotl = bool(na)
divbear = bool(na)
divbull = bool(na)

// If bar with lowest / highest is current bar, use it's value
max := hb == 0 ? close : na(max[1]) ? close : max[1]
max_rsi := hb == 0 ? rsi : na(max_rsi[1]) ? rsi : max_rsi[1]
min := lb == 0 ? close : na(min[1]) ? close : min[1]
min_rsi := lb == 0 ? rsi : na(min_rsi[1]) ? rsi : min_rsi[1]

// Compare high of current bar being examined with previous bar's high
// If curr bar high is higher than the max bar high in the lookback window range
if close > max  // we have a new high
    max := close  // change variable "max" to use current bar's high value
    max
if rsi > max_rsi  // we have a new high
    max_rsi := rsi  // change variable "max_rsi" to use current bar's RSI value
    max_rsi
if close < min  // we have a new low
    min := close  // change variable "min" to use current bar's low value
    min
if rsi < min_rsi  // we have a new low
    min_rsi := rsi  // change variable "min_rsi" to use current bar's RSI value
    min_rsi

// Finds pivot point with at least 2 right candles with lower value
pivoth := max_rsi == max_rsi[2] and max_rsi[2] != max_rsi[3] ? true : na
pivotl := min_rsi == min_rsi[2] and min_rsi[2] != min_rsi[3] ? true : na

// Detects divergences between price and indicator with 1 candle delay so it filters out repeating divergences
if max[1] > max[2] and rsi[1] < max_rsi and rsi <= rsi[1]
    divbear := true
    divbear
if min[1] < min[2] and rsi[1] > min_rsi and rsi >= rsi[1]
    divbull := true
    divbull


// Plots divergences and pivots with offest
l = divbear ? label.new(bar_index - 1, rsi[1] + 1, 'BEAR', color=color.red, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_down, yloc=yloc.price, size=size.small) : divbull ? label.new(bar_index - 1, rsi[1] - 1, 'BULL', color=color.green, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_up, yloc=yloc.price, size=size.small) : pivoth ? label.new(bar_index - 2, max_rsi + 1, 'PIVOT', color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_down, yloc=yloc.price, size=size.small) : pivotl ? label.new(bar_index - 2, min_rsi - 1, 'PIVOT', color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white, style=label.style_label_up, yloc=yloc.price, size=size.small) : na

// Shorter labels
if shrt
    label.set_text(l, na)
// Hides pivots or labels
if piv and (pivoth or pivotl) or hidel
    label.delete(l)

//strategy code 


//checking if current time lies in the defined time period 

timeCond = i_period_start < time  and time < i_period_end

//Defining condition for bullish divergence long and  bearish divergence short
buyCondition = (divbull  and strategy.position_size <= 0) ? true : false
sellCondition = (divbear and strategy.position_size <= 0) ? true : false

if buyCondition and timeCond 
    strategy.entry('long', strategy.long, qty=1000)
    
if strategy.position_size > 0
    effective_sl = strategy.position_avg_price * i_stop_prcnt / 100
    effective_exp = strategy.position_avg_price * i_exposure / 100
    strategy.exit(id='long exit', from_entry='long', comment='long closed', stop=effective_sl , profit=effective_exp)
```

I tried looking on all the pinescript resources but I couldn't find enough examples for a pinescript v5 strategy. If there are resources for pinescript v5 strategy examples, please guide me to those as well.
Thank you.

Comment: I can see that there are many deals triggered by this on `BTC`. What's your ticker and timeframe? Where do you expect to enter a trade but it doesn't? Give us a screenshot or a timestamp.

Comment: This line `strategy.exit(id='long exit', from_entry='long', comment='long closed', stop=effective_sl , profit=effective_exp)` must be `strategy.exit(id='long exit', from_entry='long', comment='long closed', stop=effective_sl , limit=effective_exp)`

Comment: @vitruvius  It's not taking more than 3 trades on any BTC pair, however if you use this indicator -
https://www.tradingview.com/script/42wcFfql-Relative-Strength-Index-Divergences-Libertus/

You will see there are many bullish divergences. It should take trades on at least most of them, instead the total trades are not more than 4, that too on 1h and 4h.

Comment: @AndreyD I changed the `profit=` to `limit=`, but it did not help the strategy to enter/exit trades any better I think.

Comment: With your default settings you run this strategy for two weeks only and it takes ALL the trades it should.

Comment: @vitruvius Sorry, I just saw I had the time condition set in the code, I thought I removed it long back. Lol. Thank you for your persistent answer!

Answer (score 0):

CORRECTION/SOLUTION - The code is working fine for v5 pinescript. I had put a time input and forgot to edit its default values. My bad.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer ?